# How to write a bash alias for "compile and run"?

Tags: bash, alias

I'm under linux and always run my test program like this:

```
g++ MyFileName.cpp -std=c++11 && ./a.out
```

I don't with to type so much, I wish to write a bash alias in my .bashrc, named c++run, so that I can:

```
c++run MyFileName.cpp
```

It compiles and if success, run ./a.out

How to write such an alias? If not possible, write a bash function?

Comment: Why are you not using a build system, such as GNU Make?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use function instead of alias, or a script. Also tinycc could do what you want, AFAIK.